# How to validate if a user logged in with Google is still valid?

Tags: authentication, google-authentication, refresh-token, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm running .NET Core v3.1 and Blazor and have implemented authorization using Google limited to our domain in Google G Suite as mentioned here: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/forcing-users-sign-in-gsuite-domain-account/

Login/logout is working fine, but when the user who logged in is blocked or removed in Google G Suite the user stays logged in into my application until he logs out from the application. When he doesn't logs out he can keep using the application.

I'm looking for a refresh every hour.

This is my login.cshtml.cs:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var GoogleUser = User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
            if (GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    RedirectUri = Request.Host.Value,
                    IssuedUtc = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                };
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(GoogleUser), authProperties);
            }
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
```

I already added `IssuedUtc` and `ExpiresUtc` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the ability to call Google APIs (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group) to get this information, but, before you can do that, the G-Suite Domain Admin has to authorize that access using https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing

This explains the process:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

You will want to see this GitHub repo for code samples:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client

Here is some psudo code:

```
string[] Scopes = {
DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup,
DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser
};

GoogleCredential credential;

//redirectUrl = this.Request.Host.Value;
string keyfilepath = "yourKeyFile.json";

using (var stream = new FileStream(keyfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // As we are using admin SDK, we need to still impersonate user who has admin access
    //  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
            .CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser(EmailOfGoogleDomainAdmin);
}

// Create Directory API service.
var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "ApplicationName",
});

// G Suite User to get information about
// This test user should be suspended
var gs_email = UserToCHeck;

var request = service.Users.Get(gs_email);

var result = request.Execute();

Console.WriteLine("Full Name: {0}", result.Name.FullName);
Console.WriteLine("Email:     {0}", result.PrimaryEmail);
Console.WriteLine("ID:        {0}", result.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Is Admin:  {0}", result.IsAdmin);
Console.WriteLine("Is Suspended:  {0}", result.Suspended);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply. I'll look into it and get back to you after the weekend.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've authorized access to the API's you suggested, I did use the `.readonly` versions. But how do I get the data? I can't find an example? Do I need an additional call to Google to check if the user is still valid? If so how and when do I do that?

Comment: I updated my original answer to provide some samples.

Comment: Thanks Michael, your solution works. I've marked it as an answer.